# advice on checking username availability in an edittext in android

Tags: java, android

I have a project where there is a registration form with multiple fields.One of the fields is for user name.I want to check whether the value entered in the edittext for the username is available or not.So i tried using onfocuslistener , that is when the ishasfocus variable is false a request goes to the server.I have tried the following:

```
txtusername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if (!hasFocus)
                {

                     username=txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
                if(username.equals("achuthan")){
                    txtusername.setError("Username exsists!");
                    isUsernameValid=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isUsernameValid=true;
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

and in the button click for the submit button i check  whether `isUsernameValid` is true.

The issue is this:

The checking whether the username is valid happens when i leave the edittext to the next one.So when i type an invalid username(achuthan in this case) and then leave to the next field the boolean value is set as false and the error is shown.Now if i correct the username to a valid one ,but if i dont leave focus of the edittext and press submit , the form is not getting accepted(Since the boolean value has not changed to true, which happens in the else part).How do i resolve this issue?

EDIT:Tried this didnt work

```
txtusername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                isUsernameValid=true;
                if (!hasFocus||hasFocus)
                {
                    //check with server if username exsists,if exsists isUserNameValid=true else false
                     username=txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
                if(username.equals("achuthan")){
                    txtusername.setError("Username exsists!");
                    isUsernameValid=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isUsernameValid=true;
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: (Disclaimer: I do not know the Android API.) Maybe you can simply set `isUsernameValid = true` as the first statement in your method - regardless whether it gained or losed focus. Then just check the focus and try the validation.

Comment: see edits it didnt work..:(

Comment: Your `if` now makes no sense! Now you _always_ validate it. Let it as `if (!hasFocus) ...` and remove the `else` part. I will make it answer to make my suggestion clear.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know the Android API, the following might work:

```
txtusername.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        resetUsernameErrorState();
        if (!hasFocus) {
            validateUsername();
        }
    }
});

private void resetUsernameErrorState() {
    isUsernameValid = true;
    txtusername.setError(null);
}

private void validateUsername() {
    username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
    if(username.equals("achuthan")) {
        txtusername.setError("Username exsists!");
        isUsernameValid = false;
    }
}
```

So your first reset the error state by setting your validation variable to true and removing the error flag. Second, you validate again in case your text field loses focus.

Comment: IT didnt help...When i type achuthan and i leave the edittext , the error message pops up.But when i click the edittext again the error message is gone(because of the rest method) and when i click the submit button, the form is accepted.But the name is achuthan and it should not be accepted.